# How to use app.json with Sencha Touch correctly?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I don´t find documentation about management app versions in Sencha Touch..

I am looking after production build with Sencha Cmd, sencha makes an app.json with different values in version and etcetera, but I don´t know the correct workflow with this file

How should it be managed a correct and versatile implementation in Sencha using Ext.os.version and app.json to detect (for instance) a new app version from the server-side?

I hope I explained well..

Thanks.

Comment: You talk about detecting a new app from the server-side. Are you referring to the server that would host a sencha touch app bundled and deployed as a native app on the AppStore (iOS) and Google Play (Android)? Or do you mean a server hosting the touch app as a web application?

Comment: Thanks for your response @mindparse  as a web app..